# How do I fetch column names from a db table into an array, using PostgreSQL and Ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

How can I iterate through all of the column headers in a table for a given database and add each column name individually to an array?

I know I can gather all of the information from the table using `SELECT * FROM my_table` but I need to work with just the column headers at this point. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [`pg` gem](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home)? If so, you can try this:

```
require 'pg'

# `db_config` must contain your database configuration
conn = PG::Connection.open(db_config)

column_names = conn.query("SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1").first.keys
```

Comment: I am using the gem yes. So that works, if I add a puts statement in front of it for example it will display each city, but how can I save those values into a variable or an array?

Comment: got it I tried that and it wasn't working and it was because I left my `puts` statement in there haha :p thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, `puts` is tricky because it returns `nil`. You can try using `p` instead of `puts`. The printed value will sometimes be slightly different, but the return value is equal to the value of the argument, unlike `puts`.

Comment: You could also use column_names.first.inspect to get a hash of keys and values.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='my_table'
```

as

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1
```

will not return column names if the table is empty.

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTilsjTAXyN5DghR3M2U4c8w48UVxhov4-8igMpd1@mail.gmail.com