# Create hash with keys are table names, values are column names

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I would like to iterate an array that has a database table names, I would like to create a hash like this:

```
{"table1"=>[column1,...,columnN],"table2"=>[column1,...,columnM]...}
```

This is what I did so far:

```
arr_table_names = ['table1','table2','table3']

arr_table_names.each do |table|  
 rs = pg_conn.exec 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id=0'
 column_names = rs.nfields
   h = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
   h[table].push ??? column_names ?? I don't know how in this line

end
```

I tried to use Sebastian's solution, but got a syntax error:

```
def check_tables_same_content(table1,table2)
   result = %w[#{table1} #{table2}].each_with_object([]) do |table, arr|
    arr << { table.to_sym => @pg_conn.exec("SELECT * FROM #{table} WHERE false").fields }
   end
   puts result2    
 end  
check_tables_same_content('company','company2')

company.rb:21:in `exec': ERROR:  syntax error at or near "#" (PG::SyntaxError)
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM #{table1} WHERE false
                  ^
```

Note that I am not looking on how to return column names.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986443/how-do-i-fetch-column-names-from-a-db-table-into-an-array-using-postgresql-and

Comment: @Joe is right (the second answer in particular), look at `information_schema.columns` rather than trying to kludge something up with an empty query. You could also dig through the Rails/ActiveRecord PostgreSQL driver to see how it figures out table structures (and find that it consults the system tables too).

Comment: Not sure this is what the user requested. See comments

Answer (score -1):

Use `.map` to create a new array and pass the block.  This should work:

```
arr_table_names.map do |table|  
    rs = pg_conn.execute "SELECT * FROM #{table} WHERE Id=0"
    {table => rs.fields}
end
```

Update, you wanted a hash with the table names as keys, and columns as values so:

```
arr_table_names = ['table1','table2','table3']
hash = {}
arr_table_names.each do |table|  
    rs = pg_conn.execute "SELECT * FROM #{table} WHERE Id=0"
    hash[table] = rs.fields
end
```

Update 2, you want the row data as an array for each column(key) in the hash:

```
arr_table_names = ['table1','table2','table3']
hash = {}
arr_table_names.each do |table|  
  rows = pg_conn.execute "SELECT * FROM #{table}"
  hash[table] = rows.entries.map(&:values)
end
```

Comment: lacostenycoder, Your code work perfect, but I want the value of the hash to be an array of all the returned rows not the column names. Thanks

Comment: are you doing this in a rails project or just plain ruby?